# Too many connection for Spring Boot Application and Apache storm

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, websocket, apache-storm

I am using spring boot application for websocket and in my storm project i am calling the spring boot application everytime to publish real time sensor data i,e per 5 minutes it is establishing 5000 connection so how to avoid this problem?

Is there any way to do connection pooling for spring boot connection in the Apache storm project?

String boot application controller class:

```
private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(GreetingController.class);
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    //logger.info("+++++++Sending Greetinge+++++++" + message);
    //Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello greetings, " + message.getName() + "!");
}
@MessageMapping("/orignal")
@SendTo("/topic/orignal")
public Map<String, Object> orignal(Map<String, Object> orignal) throws Exception {
//  logger.info("+++++++Sending orignale+++++++" + orignal);
    //System.out.println("Sending orignal");
    //Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    return orignal;
}
@MessageMapping("/tupple")
@SendTo("/topic/tupple")
public Map<String, Object> tupple(Map<String, Object>  tupple) throws       Exception {
    logger.info("+++++++Sending tupple+++++++" + tupple);
    //System.out.println("Sending tupple");
    //Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    //String company_name=(String) tupple.get("company_name");
    /*Map<String, Object> companyMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    companyMap.put("success", true);
    companyMap.put("message", "company created successfully");*/

    return tupple;
}
@MessageMapping("/websocket")
@SendTo("/topic/websocket")
public Map<String, Object> websocket(Map<String, Object> websocket) throws Exception {
    logger.info("+++++++Sending websocket+++++++" + websocket);
    //System.out.println("Sending websocket");
    //Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    return websocket;
}
```

In storm project making connection to spring boot application:

```
private final static WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

public ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect(String endpoint) {

    Transport webSocketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient());
    List<Transport> transports = Collections.singletonList(webSocketTransport);

    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
    sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec());

    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

    /*String url = "ws://{host}:{port}/"+endpoint;
    return stompClient.connect(url, headers, new MyHandler(), "10.0.0.6", 8080);*/
    String url = "ws://*************/IoTWebSocketServer-1.2.5.RELEASE/"+endpoint;
    return stompClient.connect(url, headers, new MyHandler());
}

public void subscribeGreetings(String topic,StompSession stompSession) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    stompSession.subscribe(topic, new StompFrameHandler() {

        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
            return byte[].class;
        }

        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
        }
    });
}

public void sendHello(StompSession stompSession,String message) {
    String jsonHello = "{ \"name\" : \""+message+"\" }";
    stompSession.send("/app/hello", jsonHello.getBytes());

}

private class MyHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
    public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HelloClient helloClient = new HelloClient();
    String endPoint = "hello";
    ListenableFuture<StompSession> f = helloClient.connect(endPoint);
    StompSession stompSession = f.get();

    String topic= "/topic/greetings";
    helloClient.subscribeGreetings(topic,stompSession);

    String  message = "hieeeeeeeeeeeeeeee message";
    helloClient.sendHello(stompSession,message);

    HelloClient helloClienttupple = new HelloClient();
    String endPointtupple = "tupple";
    ListenableFuture<StompSession> ftupple = helloClient.connect(endPointtupple);
    StompSession stompSessiontupple = ftupple.get();

    String topictupple= "/topic/tupple";
    helloClient.subscribeGreetings(topictupple,stompSessiontupple);

    String  messagetupple = "hieeeeeeeeeeeeeeee tupple";
    helloClienttupple.sendHello(stompSessiontupple,messagetupple);
    JSONObject companyMap = new JSONObject();
    companyMap.put("name", "Mahabali");
    companyMap.put("num", new Integer(100));
    companyMap.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
    companyMap.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
    System.out.println(companyMap.toString());
    stompSessiontupple.send("/app/tupple", companyMap.toString().getBytes());
    //Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

This the connection establishing code:

t

```
ry{
            logger.info("++++Websocket Gateway packet++++" + topicId); 
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject();
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
            jsonObject.put("MAC_IMEI", topicId);
            jsonObject.put("TIME", eventTime);
            jsonObject.put("DEVICE", "GATEWAY");
            jsonObject.put("GATEWAY", nJsonArray);
            array.put(jsonObject);
            jsonObject1.put("GATEWAY", array);
            HelloClient helloClientwebsocket = new HelloClient();
            String endPointwebsocket = "websocket";
            ListenableFuture<StompSession> fwebsocket = helloClientwebsocket.connect(endPointwebsocket);
            StompSession stompSessionwebsocket = fwebsocket.get();
            String topicwebsocket= "/topic/websocket";
            helloClientwebsocket.subscribeGreetings(topicwebsocket,stompSessionwebsocket);                
            stompSessionwebsocket.send("/app/websocket", jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            logger.info("Gateway exception");   
            logger.error("++++Exception caught during sending the sensor details in the new websocket server++++"+e);


    }
```

Comment: Please use connection pooling